# Filtering across a relationship doesn't work in my admin list page

Tags: python, django

I have an admin setup that includes a lookup that spans a relationship, "school__year" as one of my list_filter options. This appears to work properly (the set of distinct years shows up as options to filter by in the list page sidebar) but when I click on them I get a 302 redirect to "/?e=1".

This is the same behavior as if you put random query strings in the URL, even though "/?school__year=2010" should be OK because of the entry in list_filter.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11670

The easiest workaround is to not name your columns 'year'.